# mod_geoIP installation help?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, geolocation

I'm installing mod_geoIP for cpanel based on these [instructions](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache3/CustomMods) (not very detailed, hence this question)

At this point, I've installed the module as instructed.  I've also downloaded the csv file for the GeoLite Country. AM I missing anything?

I assume the next step is to create the entry in my .htaccess file for allowed countries like so:

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIPCountryWhois.csv

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE US AllowCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE CA AllowCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE MX AllowCountry

Deny from all
Allow from env=AllowCountry
```

Does it look like I'm missing anything?  Also is there a way to test this?

Comment: Can you see GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE being set? For example using $_ENV["GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE"] is some php file.

Answer (score 3):

I know that your question is a bit old, but it could use an answer anyway.

I think the only thing you did wrong was that you have to use the Binary DB file not the CSV file.

If you're using a Debian-based distribution, do this:

1. Install Apache2 and mod_geoip:  `sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-geoip`
2. Download one of these:

   - GeoLiteCountry (country-level detail only):  `sudo wget -O /etc/apache2/GeoIP.dat.gz http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz`
   - GeoLiteCity (country, state, and city-level detail):  `sudo wget -O /etc/apache2/GeoIP.dat.gz http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz`
3. Gunzip it:  `sudo gunzip /etc/apache2/GeoIP.dat.gz`
4. Edit the appropriate host file:  `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default` (or whichever you wish)
5. Insert the following into that file:
   `GeoIPEnable On`
   `GeoIPDBFile /etc/apache2/GeoIP.dat`
6. `sudo service apache2 restart` or `sudo invoke-rc.d apache2 restart`
7. Then use the ENV variables within Apache2 or your favorite programming language.

If `geoip-bin` package exists, you could probably use that instead of downloading it in step 2.  I haven't used it, so I'm not sure at what path that file would be.

The above steps give me these ENV variables:

```
GEOIP_ADDR          99.99.99.99
GEOIP_CONTINENT_CODE    NA
GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE      US
GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME      United States
GEOIP_REGION        TX
GEOIP_REGION_NAME       Texas
GEOIP_CITY          San Antonio
GEOIP_DMA_CODE      641
GEOIP_AREA_CODE     210
GEOIP_LATITUDE      29.488899
GEOIP_LONGITUDE     -98.398697
GEOIP_POSTAL_CODE       78218
```